# How to see cyrillic data in json use node.js restful API

Tags: node.js, api, restful-url

I have a cyrillic data in json format and in the API I see the data like this:

```
stations    
0   
Map_code    0
NAME_IME    "Bjala river - Smoljan"
NAME_CYR    "���� ���� - ��. ������"
Alertlevelwebsite   1
CODENUM 1
```

I want to display `NAME_CYR    "���� ���� - ��. ������"` with UTF-8 or CP_1251 encode but I don't know how..?

The code:

```
    app.route('/stations')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    // omitted
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*', 'Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');

    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM sel_alert_level s;`, function (error, result) {
      if (error)
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Грешна заявка. Опитай отново !"})
      stations = result;
      res.json({ stations })
    });
  });
```

**I try to put** `res.set({ 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });` **before**  `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*', 'Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');` like this:

```
      app.route('/stations')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    // omitted
    res.set({ 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*', 'Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');

    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM sel_alert_level s;`, function (error, result) {
      if (error)
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Грешна заявка. Опитай отново !"})
      stations = result;
      res.json({ stations })
    });
  });
```

But this not work for me..

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the headers from the response (use dev tools if you're using the browser). JSON is UTF-8 by default and if you use express it should be fine, but just double check.

If that doesn't work - use  `res.set({ 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });` (Express again).

Comment: Can you check my update I try your way but not work for me or may be this line of code is not where it should be ?

Comment: Check what headers do you get in your request/response